# How can I calculate this triple integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, substitution, multiple-integral

The formula is:
$$
\iiint_G {|xy| \over{x^2}} dxdydz
$$
$G$ is defined by the inequality: $\sqrt{x^2+y^2} < z < \sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$

I tried to use this substitute:
$$
\begin{cases}
x = rsin(\phi)\\
y = rcos(\phi)\\
z = z
\end{cases}
$$

So $G$ transforms to $r < z < \sqrt{1 - r^2}$, but for me it's not much better. Other suggestions?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: The region $G$ is between two surfaces.  Take them one at a time. To find the boundary of an inequality, change it to an equality and sketch the boundary.  Then figure out which side of the boundary your inequality refers to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$G_1=\left\{(\theta,r,z)\Big{|}\,\,\frac{\pi}{4}\le\theta\le\frac{3\pi}{4} ,\,0\le r\le 1 \, , r\le z\le\sqrt{1-r^2}\right\}\\
G_2=\left\{(\theta,r,z)\Big{|}\,\,\frac{5\pi}{4}\le\theta\le\frac{7\pi}{4} ,\,0\le r\le 1 \, , r\le z\le\sqrt{1-r^2}\right\}
$$
 We have $G=G_1\cup G_2$.Since $G$ is symmetric with respect $x-$  axes and $y-$ axes, thus
$$
\iiint_G {|xy| \over{x^2}} dxdydz=4\int_{0}^{\frac {\pi}{4}}\int_{0}^{1} \int_{r}^{\sqrt{1-r^2}}\tan\theta \,\text{dz dr d}\theta
$$